# Make active admin return a value from an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Im trying to make a filter with a belongs to assosiation to get checkboxes with options.

I tried to use this from the documentation(https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages.md)

```
filter :author, as: :check_boxes, collection: proc { Author.all }
```

But that will return the options as a list of elements like this

```
#<AUTHOR:0X007FAA63DF5F60>
```

I want it to return the name of the author, it have the name in the migration as a string.

I had a similar problem in the forms, there i ended up making my own partial.

Am using rails 4.1.4, with active admin from the github https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin

Comment: have you tried `Author.pluck(:name)` this will return an `Array` of all the author names.

Comment: Thanks, to get the filter to work i needed to use Author.pluck(:navn, :id)

Comment: glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to fix that.

You can define a `display_name` method on your model with returns the Author name or you do this:

```
filter :author, as: :check_boxes, collection: proc { Author.all.map{|a| [a.name, a.id] } }
```

Or this:

```
filter :author, as: :check_boxes, collection: proc { Author.pluck(a.name, a.id) }
```